# Q Learning Model Not Improving Over Time

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

I'm working with the code shown below from chapter 11 of the book Predictive Analytics with Tensorflow (code given on [GitHub](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Predictive-Analytics-with-TensorFlow/tree/master/Chapter11)). It tries to set up a basic Q learning function to trade historical stock data. I've modified it a little bit to get new historical data for whatever stock is entered.

I'm finding that the q learning is not improving much and seems to be "exploring" a lot even though I have my epsilon set quite low. This is an outputted plot of all the final portfolio sizes from each of the 100 runs:

[image: finalportfolioplot]

I'd like to see this plot to be in more of an upward trend, rather than all over the place like it is. I've run the model using 500 episodes and 100 episodes, and I've tried extremely adjusting the epsilon, learning rate, and gamma to try and get it to improve upon the last run, but am not successful. Granted I'm still new to q learning. Would someone be able to tell me what to implement to get it working better? And maybe a way to save/load the models that are generated with the best final portfolio sizes???? Thanks!

```
from yahoo_finance import Share
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random
import tensorflow as tf
import os
from datetime import datetime
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
import warnings
from pandas_datareader import data as web
import pandas as pd

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
ops.reset_default_graph()

# create an empty list to store the loss values in so we can plot them later
final_prof_list = []

class DecisionPolicy:
    def select_action(self, current_state, step):
        pass

    def update_q(self, state, action, reward, next_state):
        pass


# class RandomDecisionPolicy(DecisionPolicy):
#     def __init__(self, actions):
#         self.actions = actions

#     def select_action(self, current_state, step):
#         action = self.actions[random.randint(0, len(self.actions) - 1)]
#         return action


class QLearningDecisionPolicy(DecisionPolicy):
    def __init__(self, actions, input_dim):
        self.epsilon = 0.01 # default 0.5, the lesser, the lesser it'll explore
        self.gamma = 0.99 # typically between 0.8 and 0.99. The larger, the smaller the discount, which means agent cares more about long term reward.
        self.learning_rate = 0.99 # Higher learning rate means more the agent will learn more from previous step, 0.0001 - 0.99
        self.actions = actions
        output_dim = len(actions)
        h1_dim = 200

        self.x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, input_dim])
        self.y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [output_dim])
        W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([input_dim, h1_dim]))
        b1 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[h1_dim]))
        h1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(self.x, W1) + b1)
        W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([h1_dim, output_dim]))
        b2 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[output_dim]))
        self.q = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h1, W2) + b2)

        loss = tf.square(self.y - self.q)
        self.train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.learning_rate).minimize(loss) # GradientDescentOptimizer 
        self.sess = tf.Session()
        self.sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

    def select_action(self, current_state, step):
        threshold = min(self.epsilon, step / 1000.)
        if random.random() < threshold:
            # Exploit best option with probability epsilon
            action_q_vals = self.sess.run(self.q, feed_dict={self.x: current_state})
            action_idx = np.argmax(action_q_vals)  # TODO: replace w/ tensorflow's argmax
            action = self.actions[action_idx]
        else:
            # Explore random option with probability 1 - epsilon
            action = self.actions[random.randint(0, len(self.actions) - 1)]
        return action

    def update_q(self, state, action, reward, next_state):
        action_q_vals = self.sess.run(self.q, feed_dict={self.x: state})
        next_action_q_vals = self.sess.run(self.q, feed_dict={self.x: next_state})
        next_action_idx = np.argmax(next_action_q_vals)
        action_q_vals[0, next_action_idx] = reward + self.gamma * next_action_q_vals[0, next_action_idx]
        action_q_vals = np.squeeze(np.asarray(action_q_vals))
        self.sess.run(self.train_op, feed_dict={self.x: state, self.y: action_q_vals})


def run_simulation(policy, initial_budget, initial_num_stocks, prices, hist, debug=False):
    budget = initial_budget
    num_stocks = initial_num_stocks
    shares_to_buy = 10
    share_value = 0
    transitions = list()
    for i in range(len(prices) - hist - 1):
        if i % 100 == 0:
            print('progress {:.2f}%'.format(float(100*i) / (len(prices) - hist - 1)))
        current_state = np.asmatrix(np.hstack((prices[i:i+hist], budget, num_stocks)))
        current_portfolio = budget + num_stocks * share_value
        action = policy.select_action(current_state, i)
        share_value = float(prices[i + hist + 1])
        if action == 'Buy' and budget >= share_value:
            budget -= share_value
            num_stocks += shares_to_buy
        elif action == 'Sell' and num_stocks > 0:
            budget += share_value
            num_stocks -= shares_to_buy
        else:
            action = 'Hold'
        new_portfolio = budget + num_stocks * share_value
        reward = new_portfolio - current_portfolio
        next_state = np.asmatrix(np.hstack((prices[i+1:i+hist+1], budget, num_stocks)))
        transitions.append((current_state, action, reward, next_state))
        policy.update_q(current_state, action, reward, next_state)

    portfolio = budget + num_stocks * share_value
    if debug:
        print('${}\t{} shares'.format(budget, num_stocks))
    print('Final portfolio size : ', portfolio)
    final_prof_list.append(portfolio)

    return portfolio


def run_simulations(policy, budget, num_stocks, prices, hist):
    # Number of runs to run
    num_tries = 100 # default 100
    # create a saver to save and try loading models
    saver = tf.train.Saver()

    final_portfolios = list()
    for i in range(num_tries):
        final_portfolio = run_simulation(policy, budget, num_stocks, prices, hist)
        final_portfolios.append(final_portfolio)
    avg, std = np.mean(final_portfolios), np.std(final_portfolios)
    return avg, std


def get_prices(share_symbol, start_date, end_date, cache_filename):
    try:
        stock_prices = np.load(cache_filename)
    except IOError:
        ex = 'yahoo'
        df = web.DataReader(share_symbol, ex, start, end)
        stock_prices = df['Open']
        df=stock_prices.values

        #share = Share(share_symbol)
        #stock_hist = share.get_historical(start_date, end_date)
        #stock_prices = [stock_price['Open'] for stock_price in stock_hist]
        np.save(cache_filename, df)
    return stock_prices

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = datetime(2016, 1, 1)
    end = datetime.now()
    ticker = 'RKDA'
    prices = get_prices(ticker, start, end, r'./resource/' + ticker + '_stock_prices.npy')
    actions = ['Buy', 'Sell', 'Hold']
    hist = 100
    #policy = RandomDecisionPolicy(actions)
    policy = QLearningDecisionPolicy(actions, hist + 2)
    budget = 1000.0
    num_stocks = 0
    avg, std = run_simulations(policy, budget, num_stocks, prices, hist)
    print(avg, std)

    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.plot([np.mean(final_prof_list[i-2:i]) for i in range(len(final_prof_list))])
    plt.draw()
    plt.savefig('final_prof_list.png', dpi=100)
    plt.show()


# https://books.google.ca/books?id=mEFPDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA477&lpg=PA477&dq=predictive+analytics+with+tensorflow+chapter+11+stock&source=bl&ots=xs_eJywWF7&sig=ACfU3U2TB1-LmmpSwo3iHmQZg8BPlOk1MA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjvg6Oht5XkAhWRneAKHe3mAeMQ6AEwDHoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=true
```